# How to delete multiple occurences IDs in a DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've tried it now for about 3 hours and I don't get the result I want to have.

I have a dataset like this:

```
orderId name   quantity  order item
   1      1       2          1
   1      1       4          2
   1      1       1          3
   2      2       1          1
   3      3       10         1
   3      3       3          2
```

and I want to delete the multiple occurences of the orderIds that I have an output dataframe with only unique IDs:

```
orderId userId order item
   1    1         1
   2    2         1
   3    3         1
```

So that I can sum up, how often a user placed an order.

Comment: `df.drop_duplicates('orderId')`?

Answer (score 1):

you've been searching 3 hours for this:

```
df2.drop_duplicates(['orderId'])

   orderId  name  quantity  order  item
0        1     1         2      1   NaN
3        2     2         1      1   NaN
4        3     3        10      1   NaN
```

Comment: Thank you. Im feeling like a big fool right now :D

Comment: hehe not to worry. We all have at some point during our lives

Comment: Yeah you are so right :D But well Im coding already the whole day and try to improve :) Thank you for that!

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3],'B':[2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4]})
```

```
    A   B
0   1   2
1   1   2
2   1   2
3   2   3
4   2   3
5   2   3
6   3   4
7   3   4
8   3   4
```

```
df.drop_duplicates((['A','B'])) # in your case its orderId
```

```
    A   B
0   1   2
3   2   3
6   3   4
```

Inside of `drop_duplicates()` method you can select which columns to check for duplicates, it also accepts useful parameter `keep` which can be set to `first` or `last`.

Comment: Thank you. Im feeling like a big fool right now :D

Comment: Now you will remember it forever, that's the beauty of learning

Comment: Haha I think so and your are right. Thanks much mate :) 
But I dont get why people downgrade my question :/